# Can the higher oxides of nitrogen, like nitrogen pentoxide, be used as oxidisers in rocket engines?

Tags: engines, fuel, chemistry, oxidizer

Both nitrous oxide (N<sub>2</sub>O) and dinitrogen tetroxide (N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub>) are used in storable propellant combinations, so, simply as a continuation, can the higher oxides of nitrogen (N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>5</sub>, N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>6</sub>, etc.) still be used in an engine? Is it practical but just lacking in performance, or unstable/difficult like ozone?

I know this is very probably a silly question and is absolutely made in total ignorance, but I just couldn't find anything on it and from a highly peripheral point of view it seems like a good idea, or is at least interesting.

Comment: I don't think N2O6 exists.

Answer (score 12):

## Not likely

N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>5</sub>
Well, the stuff *IS* a very strong oxidizer.

But considering that the solid form is a hard white salt-like substance,
and it melts at 41 °C, and boils at 47 °C, so it can be a wee bit tricky to pump through an engine.

Add the fact that it quite happily decomposes down to NO<sub>2</sub> + O<sub>2</sub> at temperatures well below its freezing point, and  you have one spectacularly uncooperative oxidizer.

N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>6</sub> is so unstable, it decomposes before it can be detected.
Same for N<sub>3</sub>O<sub>6</sub>.

N<sub>4</sub>O<sub>6</sub>, more properly N(NO<sub>2</sub>)<sub>3</sub>, does exist in that it can be made in a lab, but it refuses to sit still in large enough quantities and for long enough for its physical properties to be examined. This does not bode well for its use in a rocket engine.

As a rough rule of thumb, the more N and O one crams into a single molecule, the more the molecule will resemble high explosives rather than usable rocket oxidizer.

Could I not interest you in more tractable oxidizers, like dioxygen difluoride, better known by the cuddly name of "FOOF"?
It should be more stable, *and* deliver better I<sub>sp</sub> than these higher order oxides of nitrogen. (And yet appeal to the masochistic mad scientist that wanted to play with high order nitrogen oxides.)

Comment: The classic succinct rundown on the hair-eliminating nature of FOOF is Derek Lowe's https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/things-i-won-t-work-dioxygen-difluoride , which features the word "explosion" rather more often than your Kerbals will like. He describes the report of one hardy explorer: "If the paper weren't laid out in complete grammatical sentences and published in JACS, you'd swear it was the work of a violent lunatic. I ran out of vulgar expletives after the second page."

Comment: @TomGoodfellow I've managed to find the original paper by A. G. Streng: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/jklein2/O2F2.pdf

Comment: Not the worst idea. Somebody wanted to use O17 ozone.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms - just ... wow! coming from Lowe's reference my expectations of that paper were already high but it exceeded them just the same. Thank you kindly for that early Xmas gift.

Comment: Why would FOOF deliver a high ISP?  Those fluorines are heavy and will bind to a single hydrogen each.  You're going to get a high molecular weight in your exhaust and thus a lower exhaust velocity.  Is it energetic enough to overcome that major disadvantage?

Comment: @TomGoodfellow Would Derek Lowe's [hexanitrohexaazaisowurtzitane](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/things-i-won-t-work-hexanitrohexaazaisowurtzitane) be more appropriate for consideration here, given its nitrogen/oxygen composition? I don't think it's really an oxidizer though - more of a mono-propellent :-)

Comment: Even if N2O5 is a solid, it could still be very useful. I'd heard of some theoretical solid motors that use solid LOX just for the performance so surely something as efficient (compared to other solids) as N2O5 would be perfect, especially considering its (probably) hypergolic

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking Oops, I was stupidly thinking of chlorine.

Comment: @ReubenFarley-Hall But you don't want your oxidizer to spontaneously go boom.

Comment: @LorenPechtel quite right, I should've known they live strictly in the castles of spain

Comment: A fascinating thing about $\text{N}_2\text{O}_5$ in the solid form being _"a hard white salt-like substance"_ is that it is not only salt-like, but actually IS a proper salt. Its name is [nitronium nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nitronium_nitrate) $[\text{NO}_2]^+[\text{NO}_3]^-$ and it has separate nitronium cations ionically bound with nitrate anions. In the liquid and gas phases, however, it goes back to covalently bound compound.